# Do Workshop codes work in multiple platforms?

Tags: overwatch

Do custom Workshop game modes work on all platforms or just the one where it was created?

As an example, let's say that I create a Workshop gamemode on PC, can my friend use the same code on PS4 to get my Workshop Configuration?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have Overwatch on PC and PS4 and **the codes work cross-platform**.

Source: Tested it multiple times myself.